# Парсинг RSS без дублей

Tags: php, rss

Мне нужно парсить rss ленту и постить полученные данные в cms, постингом в cms и парсингом самой rss ленты проблем нет. Проблема в дублях новостей, была мысль записывать pubDate последней новости в файл, после чего проверять его, т.е. вычислять обновления и постить последнюю запись из rss... Так потом подумал, а что если будет несколько новых записей? Вообщем хз, как правильно поступить, помогите решить, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов масса...

- Можно сохранять дату и время
     последней новости. А, затем, в цикле
     перебирать ленту и постить только те
     новости, которые идут после
     предварительно сохраненной временной
     отметки.
- Можно проделать тоже самое, но с
     сохранением URL последнего
     добавленного источника.
- Если есть возможность прямого доступа
     к базе данных, можно создать поле для
     записи URL источника, и наложить на
     него ограничение по уникальности, а
     посты слать через INSERT IGNORE INTO.
     В этом случае MySQL отработает по
     тихому (без ошибок), но добавит
     только новые записи.

Comment: Спасибо, тогда еще один вопрос. У меня из rss получился многомерный массив, можно привести пример как определить все записи в массиве которые уже старые записи, т.е. к примеру у меня есть ссылка на последнюю добавленую мной новость, как узнать что идет дальше чтоб сделать им unset и оставить в массиве только новые записи ?

Comment: <p>Думаю можно обойтись и без unset. Используйте обычный цикл. Что-то типа:</p>
<pre>
$is_new = false; // флаг обработки новых записей
foreach( $array as $item ){
    if( !$is_new ){
        if( /*проверка последней записи*/ ) $is_new = true;
    }else{
        // Постим новую запись куда следует
    }
}
</pre>
<p>Здесь:</p>
<ul>
<li>$array - наш массив</li>
<li>$item - элемент массива в текущей итерации цикла</li>
</ul>